# Why \001 is added when strcat is invoked

Tags: c, strcat

Look at the following code:

```
char chs[100] = "Hello World";
char token[100];
int pos = -1;
while((current = chs[++pos]) != '"'){
      strcat(token, &current);
}
```

But the output is :

```
H\001e\001l\001l\001o\001 \001W\001o\001r\001l\001d
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @mbratch The output is supposed to be Hello World

Comment: @Foredoomed You're trying to strip the quotes surrounding the string literal? The quotes are not actually a part of the string to begin with! Maybe you should start by reading a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @Foredoomed, but is this just supposed to be a string copy from `chs` to `token`? If so, then that's what `strcpy` is for. You would just  do `strcpy(token, chs);` and be done. No loop required. Or is some other purpose intended? If you want to use `strcat`, it requires both string parameters to be zero terminated. So you'd at least need to set `token[0] = '\0'` to start before the loop, as I had mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strcat() needs a null-terminated string as it's input. so strcat(token, &current) will start reading at the address of current and keep going until it finds a null.  Just by chance, what you had in memory after current was "\001", so each time you did strcat it copied all that into token.

You should do char current[] = "\0\0" and then assign it with current[0] = chs[++pos]. That way current will always have that null termination.

Answer (score 2):

You have undefined behavior

Since your `current` is not declared, I'm guessing it is some uninitialized character.  Your 
`current = chs[++pos])` sets the character, but `strcat(token, &current);` want `current` to be a string, so you are getting some junk saved after the variable `current`.  Please post more of your sample code for further analysis

BTW `'"'` looks wrong C

Answer (score 0):

Making minimal changes this is a working version of your code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char current[2] = { 0x0, 0x0 }; // Will be null terminated
    char chs[100] = "Hello World";
    char token[100] ;
    int pos = -1;  // Destination of strcat must also be null terminated

    token[0] = '\0' ;

    // String literals does not actually have " in memory they end in \0
    while((current[0] = chs[++pos]) != '\0')
    {
            strcat(token, &current[0]); // Take the address of the first char in current                      
    }   

    printf("%s\n", token ) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

`strcat` expects both the source and destination to be null terminated strings. In your case it looks like `current` just ended up having a `\001` followed by a null terminator after it in memory.